# Adding a second y axis in BokehJS

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I have been trying to add a second y axis to my BokehJS plot, but can't seem to find how to do it correctly. In python bokeh I got it working, but in javascript it seems to work different. Here is the mininal example, how I try to create and use the second axis:

```
        var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;

        // create some data and a ColumnDataSource
        var x = Bokeh.LinAlg.linspace(-0.5, 20.5, 10);
        var y = x.map(function (v) { return v * 0.5 + 3.0; });
        var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({ data: { x: x, y: y }});

        var p = plt.figure({extra_y_ranges: {"y2": new Bokeh.Range1d({start: -1.5, end: 150})} });
        p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Axis Left';
        p.add_layout(new Bokeh.LinearAxis({ y_range_name: "y2", axis_label: 'Axis Right'}), 'right');

        // add a Line glyph
        var line = new Bokeh.Line({
            x: {field: "x"},
            y: {field: "y"},
            line_color: "#F00",
            line_width: 3
        });

        p.add_glyph(line, source);

        // add a Line glyph
        var line = new Bokeh.Line({
            x: {field: "x"},
            y: {field: "y"},
            line_color: "#FF0",
            line_width: 2,
            y_range_name: "y2"
        });

        p.add_glyph(line, source);

        plt.show(p);
```

the axis displays, but the line uses still the coordintates of the left axis.

Answer (score 2):

The trick was not to add the y_range_name property to the line directly but the the glyph object of the line added to the graph:

```
var l = p.add_glyph(line, source);
l.y_range_name = "y2";
```